# Tailwind Gradient Color stops with pseudo element "after"

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am making a component in React using Storybook. See my code:

```
<button class="btn py-4 px-16 border-0 outline-0 relative rounded-full cursor-pointer 
  after:content-[attr(data-text)] after:text-xl 
  after:bg-gradient-to-r after:from-[#F1B08D] after:to-[#DC675D]  bg-gradient-to-r from-[#F1B08D] to-[#DC675D] " data-text="Click me!"></button>
```

Unfortunately, `after:to-[#DC675D]` is not working.

I am expecting this output:

[image]

But I am getting this one:

[image]

In the styles, `after:to-[#DC675D]`is not showing:

[image]

This is how I done it on React:

```
const colors = color?.split(" ");
  const newColors = colors?.map((color) => `after:${color}`).join(" ");
  console.log(newColors);
  return (
    <button
      className={`btn py-4 px-16 border-0 outline-0 relative rounded-full cursor-pointer 
      after:content-[attr(data-text)] after:text-xl 
      ${newColors} ${blocked ? "w-full" : ""} ${color} ${classes}`}
      onClick={onClick}
      data-text={text}
    ></button>
  );
```

where `color` value is: `bg-gradient-to-r from-[#F1B08D] to-[#DC675D]`

I have searched it on ChatGPT but no luck. Your response is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can't use dynamic class names https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Comment: Hi @stickyuser, if dynamic class name is the issue, why is it that only `after:to-[#DC675D]` is not working?

Comment: It is often because Tailwind finds the classes in other parts of the project code.

Comment: @stickyuser Do you have workaround for this? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS custom property (variable) to set the colors like this:

```
<main class="bg-black p-5">
  <button class="btn relative cursor-pointer rounded-full border-0 bg-gradient-to-r from-[#F1B08D] to-[#DC675D] px-16 py-4 outline-0 after:bg-gradient-to-r after:from-[#F1B08D] after:to-[--endcolor] after:text-xl after:content-[attr(data-text)]" data-text="Click me!" style="--endcolor: #DC675D"></button>
</main>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/RhtnKCOXpl

So the class `after:to-[--endcolor]` uses the custom property `--endcolor` which is set using the style attribute `style="--endcolor: #DC675D"`.

In React you can set the value and then use it in the style attribute.

```
const endcolor = "#DC675D";
```

```
<button class="[all your classes]" style={{ '--endcolor': endcolor }}></button>
```